# IIS URL Rewrite module unencoding query string

Tags: iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

We have a really simple URL rewrite rule that basically causes a 301 redirect to another domain:

```
<rewrite>
  <rule>
    <match url="^(default.aspx)?$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://some.other.domain.com" />
  </rule>
</rewrite>
```

Unfortunately, when a URL like this is encountered:

```
http://original.domain.com/?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsome.url%2F
```

The redirect URL looks like this:

```
https://some.other.domain.com/?returnUrl=https://some.url/
```

Notice how the URL encoding is lost.

Is this a bug in the URL rewrite module?  If so, how can one work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The rewrite rule has only a partial redirect URL specified.  Query string encoding is now preserved now that I changed this:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://some.other.domain.com"/>
```

...to this:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://some.other.domain.com/"/>
```

(note the trailing slash)